# Can't call function from required file in PHP

Tags: php, include

From comment.php:

```
require_once "../../lib/vendor/Tsugi/Core/LTIX.php";
$LTI = requireData(array('user_id'));
```

From included file, LTIX.php:

```
 public static function requireData($needed) {There's a function here}
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined function requireData() in /tsugi/mod/video/comment.php

requireData() is only defined once in the whole site, so I don't think it's a name overlap problem.

Am I unable to call it because it's public or static? Is there some other reason a function call from an included file mightn't work?

Update:

With LTIX::requireData(array('user_id')), I get
Fatal error: Class 'LTIX' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tsugi/mod/video/comment.php on line 8

Comment: It's a static function of a class, you need to call it's parent class then it's function. `$LTI = LTI::requireData(array('user_id'));` for instance.

Comment: requireData is a member of LTIX. When I use LTIX::requireData, I get this: Fatal error: Class 'LTIX' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tsugi/mod/video/comment.php on line 8
Including the file with the class doesn't seem to be enough to include the class.

Comment: If the class is `class LTIX { ` and the function is `public static function requireData($something)`, then this should work. If the class is named something else, then you'll need to change the class  reference.

Comment: It's "class LTIX Extends LTI". I wouldn't expect it to make a difference, but I've tried both LTIX:: and LTI:: with the same result.

Comment: Are you able to show the code from the `LTIX.php` page, perhaps with empty methods or something if there is something proprietary?

Comment: @Rasclatt It's here: https://github.com/csev/tsugi/blob/master/lib/vendor/Tsugi/Core/LTIX.php